# error: imread: invalid image file: Magick++ exception: Magick:

Tags: imagemagick, octave

I have created the images using Gimp. The image is successfully loaded by octave's imread .But when I use convert command to resize the image and try to load in octave following errors occurs.

> > warning: your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 16 bits per pixel
> >     error: imread: invalid image file: Magick++ exception: Magick: Must specify image size (/home/tensor/Documents/Projects/ML/datasets/NepaliChar/KA/resize/makeMat.m) reported by coders/gray.c:128 (ReadGRAYImage)

I am using Arch Linux with Octave version 3.8.0 and ImageMagick 6.8.8-4

Answer (score 0):

Reading a .GRAY image requires you to specify the dimensions of your image (e.g. 800x600). You have to do this because you are reading raw pixels.

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) you cannot specify the dimensions of your .GRAY image before reading it.

Comment: I don't think its the problem of dimensions of my image. When I pass -depth 8 while converting the images then it works fine in octave. But as the depth bits are just warning why is it creating problem. Anyway, I solved it by using : convert *.png -depth 8 1.png and the resulting images are loaded successfully by octave.